# flask multiple forms on the same page

Tags: python, html, forms, flask, flask-wtforms

I got a problem with my flask application, basically I have two forms in the same html page and when I submit one or the other it submits both of them at the same time. Is there any way that I could separate them somehow, so I can submit them individually?

```
@app.route('/smtp/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def smtp():
    form = UpdateSMTPForm()
    form2 = UpdateEmailAddress()
    query = Email.query.all()

    if  form.validate_on_submit():
        email = str(form.email.data)
        password = str(form.password.data)
        server = str(form.server.data)
        port = str(form.port.data)

        if tools.test_email(server, port, email, password):
            CONFIG['SMTP']['server'] = server
            CONFIG['SMTP']['port'] = port
            CONFIG['SMTP']['username'] = email
            CONFIG['SMTP']['password'] = password

            with open('config.json', 'w') as f:
                f.write(json.dumps(CONFIG))
                f.close()
        else:
            form.server.errors.append("Invalid account, be sure that you have less secure app access turned on or try with a gmail account")


    if form2.validate_on_submit():
        print('form2 email updated {}'.format(form2.email))
    else:
        print('cannot validate the second form')

    return render_template('smtp.html', config=CONFIG['SMTP'], query=query, form=form, form2=form2)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can distinguish these forms by the submit input. Just set them different id/name and check if form submission origins from this particular form by checking if its id/name is present in `request.form`.

In the first form:

`<input type="submit" id="form-submit" name="form-submit" value="Submit form">`

And the second one:

`<input type="submit" id="form2-submit" name="form2-submit" value="Submit form2">`

And logic in your view:

```
@app.route('/smtp/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def smtp():
    form = UpdateSMTPForm()
    form2 = UpdateEmailAddress()
    query = Email.query.all()

    if  "form-submit" in request.form and form.validate_on_submit():
        email = str(form.email.data)
        password = str(form.password.data)
        server = str(form.server.data)
        port = str(form.port.data)

        if tools.test_email(server, port, email, password):
            CONFIG['SMTP']['server'] = server
            CONFIG['SMTP']['port'] = port
            CONFIG['SMTP']['username'] = email
            CONFIG['SMTP']['password'] = password

            with open('config.json', 'w') as f:
                f.write(json.dumps(CONFIG))
                f.close()
        else:
            form.server.errors.append("Invalid account, be sure that you have less secure app access turned on or try with a gmail account")


    if "form2-submit" in request.form and form2.validate_on_submit():
        print('form2 email updated {}'.format(form2.email))
    else:
        print('cannot validate the second form')

    return render_template('smtp.html', config=CONFIG['SMTP'], query=query, form=form, form2=form2)
```

Comment: I've tried your code and it always fails the validation when I submit the second form, do you have any idea why is it doing that?

Comment: @TerchilăMarian did you add `<input type="submit" id="form2-submit" name="form2-submit" value="Submit form2">` to the second form?

Comment: yes I did, and It works sort of, when I input an invalid email the error pops, but when I enter a valid email address it fails the validation

Comment: I just found out that when the form2.validate_on_submit() fails it still returns the value, do you have any idea why?

Comment: Do you have `{{ form.hidden_tag() }}` in both of your forms? If it works for the first form so it should for the second one.